# Android Studio: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS on physical device

Tags: java, android, arm64

I;m building a dummy android project in android studio that uses a java plugin.
When I try to run my app on my physical device it's giving me the error

Launching 'app' on OPPO A9.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

In the build.gradle file i have specified for this
`splits { abi { enable true reset() include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a' universalApk false }`

but it's still causing the problem

and i know my phone supports the abi list because i've verified it on the hardware info app on my phone

virtual devices for API 21 arm64 can run this app but it's useless if physical devices fail, since the main goal is to make the plugin be useable on an android phone.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, it's because I have no `.so` files at all in my project, normally this will be in the plugin but my plugin doesn't have it.

So, I had to generate my own `.so` files by creating my project with c++ support to add the native code, following [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code).

Add the ABI filters as follows:

```
android {
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        }
    }
}

dependencies { 
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

In your `build.gradle` (app) file, build your `apk` and you can see that the `.so` files and `arm64` folders will be included in your `apk`.

Now you can build and run your app on your physical device.